# Which contactless temperature sensor/thermometer to use?

Tags: arduino, sensor, temperature

I want to measure the temperature of a liquid which is running inside a steel pipe. The temperature can be, at most, 200℃. I want to measure the temperature of that liquid using a sensor/thermometer placed on the outer surface of a pipe, and i need to connect this sensor/thermometer to an Arduino.

From the Arduino, I need to get temperature data which will be shown in a web application.

I have heard about the [MLX90614 infrared Thermometer](https://www.melexis.com/en/product/MLX90614/Digital-Plug-Play-Infrared-Thermometer-TO-Can), but it supports only up to 125℃. I need an industry grade sensor for my requirement. Can anyone suggest any other options?

Comment: Why does your application require a contactless thermometer?  What's the reason why a contact thermometer wouldn't work?

Comment: Pretty much anything you attach to the outside of the pipe is going to be measuring the temperature of the outside of the pipe, not whatever is inside the pipe.

Comment: contactless sensor will do the same.  ... you will have to get the sensor inside the pipe

Comment: Look for something like the Cooper-Atkins 54011-K on Amazon.  Wrap the pipe with insulation over the thermocouple for extra accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You would get a more accurate result by inserting a probe into the pipe.

If you want to use an external probe, a thermocouple or an RTD in a block than is strapped to be in intimate contact with the pipe and well insulated from the outside environment should give reasonable results for a permanent installation. A stick-on thermocouple with insulation could be used, but the adhesive may not hold up.